# How to shift values in a column based on a condition in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

Hi I have a df like this,

```
    Name    sl no   details                 score
0   Ram     1       ram is going to ooty    NaN
1   Ram     2       ram sings well          1.5
2   Ravi    1       ravi play cricket       1.0
3   Ravi    2       ravi is in chennai      NaN
4   Kumar   1       kumar passed the exam   NaN
5   Kumar   2       kumar is in town        NaN
6   Kumar   3       he left                 3.0
```

I am trying to shift the values in the score column. values should moved to the cell where `df[sl no]==1 or df[Name] is the first occurence of a name`

My expected output should be like,

```
    Name    sl no   details                 score
0   Ram     1       ram is going to ooty    1.5
1   Ram     2       ram sings well          NaN
2   Ravi    1       ravi play cricket       1.0
3   Ravi    2       ravi is in chennai      NaN
4   Kumar   1       kumar passed the exam   3.0
5   Kumar   2       kumar is in town        NaN
6   Kumar   3       he left                 NaN
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `next` in a List Comprehension

Conditionally call `next` on an iterator inside a list comprehension.

```
assert df['sl no'].eq(1).sum() == df['score'].notna().sum()

it = iter(df.score.dropna().tolist())
df['score'] = [
    next(it) if i else np.nan for i in df['sl no'].eq(1)
]
```

```
df
    Name  sl no                details  score
0    Ram      1   ram is going to ooty    1.5
1    Ram      2         ram sings well    NaN
2   Ravi      1      ravi play cricket    1.0
3   Ravi      2     ravi is in chennai    NaN
4  Kumar      1  kumar passed the exam    3.0
5  Kumar      2       kumar is in town    NaN
6  Kumar      3                he left    NaN
```

If your `assert` statement fails, there's something wrong with your data and what you're asking isn't feasible.

---

#### `loc`-based Assignment

```
v = df.score.dropna().tolist()

df['score'] = np.nan
df.loc[df['sl no'].eq(1), 'score'] = v
```

```
df
    Name  sl no                details  score
0    Ram      1   ram is going to ooty    1.5
1    Ram      2         ram sings well    NaN
2   Ravi      1      ravi play cricket    1.0
3   Ravi      2     ravi is in chennai    NaN
4  Kumar      1  kumar passed the exam    3.0
5  Kumar      2       kumar is in town    NaN
6  Kumar      3                he left    NaN
```

Comment: assert is not failing but when I run the last line I am getting `StopIteration: ` error

Comment: @pyd I think you ran the first `it = ...` command once and the other line twice. Run both of them together, and just once

Comment: @pyd Added another simple option. No replace, no groupby, no transform.

Comment: can you answer this question @coldspeed https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/32578/machine-learning-algorithm-suggestion-for-my-problem-using-nlp

Comment: @pyd good question. I'm not sure, but if you are looking to compare vectors, I'd recommend taking a look at similarity measures like cosine or haversine distance.

Comment: Is it possible to share a link with example

Answer (score 1):

You can try so:

```
df['score'] = (df['score'].replace('',np.nan).groupby(df['Name']).transform(lambda x: x.bfill().ffill()))
df.loc[df['sl no'] != 1, 'score'] = np.NaN
```

First fill the column `score` with the same values:

```
    Name  sl no               details  score
0    Ram   1     ram is going to ooty    1.5
1    Ram   2           ram sings well    1.5
2   Ravi   1        ravi play cricket    1.0
3   Ravi   2       ravi is in chennai    1.0
4  Kumar   1    kumar passed the exam    3.0
5  Kumar   2         kumar is in town    3.0
6  Kumar   3                  he left    3.0
```

And then remove where the column `sl no` is not 1

```
    Name  sl no              details  score
0    Ram   1    ram is going to ooty    1.5
1    Ram   2          ram sings well    NaN
2   Ravi   1       ravi play cricket    1.0
3   Ravi   2      ravi is in chennai    NaN
4  Kumar   1   kumar passed the exam    3.0
5  Kumar   2        kumar is in town    NaN
6  Kumar   3                 he left    NaN
```